# Segmentation fault when trying to run custom shell

Tags: c, shell, segmentation-fault

School project to make our own shell and facing segmentation fault issues.

Can someone help?

**Edit**: kind of running but "quit" doesn't trigger the exit and execvp can't run properly (says : "no such file or directory" & "or ls:invalid option -- ' "

```
void interactive_mode();
void batch_mode(char *path);
void parse(char *str,char *delimiter, char **args);
int execute(char **args);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-b") == 0) {
        batch_mode(argv[2]);
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-i") == 0) {
        interactive_mode();
    }
}
```

I suspect the segmentation fault problem derives from the interactive and batch modes code

```
void interactive_mode() {
        int quit_flag;
        char str[512];
        char *commands[128];
        char *args[128];
            
        quit_flag = 0;
        
        while(1) {
            printf("whatever> ");

            if (fgets(str,512,stdin) == NULL) {
                exit(0); //error reading
            }
            
            int i = 0;
            
            parse(str,";",commands);        //split the string into commands eg "ls -a ; ls -l" -> "ls -a ","ls -l"

            while (commands[i]!=NULL) {
                parse(commands[i]," ",args);        //split commands into arguments eg "ls -l" -> "ls","-l"
                i++;
                quit_flag = execute(args);
            }       

            if (quit_flag == 1) 
                exit(1);
        }   
    }
```

Trying to read from file:

```
void batch_mode(char *path) {
        FILE *fp;
        char str[512];
        char *commands[128];
        char *args[128];
        int res;
    
    fp = fopen(path,"r");
    
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(4);        //file not open
    }
    
    while(1) {
        if (fgets(str, 512, fp) == NULL) 
             break;
        
        int i = 0;
        
        parse(str, ";", commands);

        while (commands[i] != NULL) {
            parse(commands[i], " ", args);
            i++;
            res = execute(args);
        }
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    printf("whatever>Press Any Key to Continue\n");
    getchar();
}
```

Parsing strings:

```
void parse(char *str, char *delimiter, char **args) {
        char *pch;
        
        int i = 0;
        pch = strtok(str,delimiter);

        while (pch != NULL) {
            args[i] = pch;
            i++;
            pch = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        }

        args[i] = NULL; 
    }
```

Executing with fork:

```
int execute(char **args) {
        char path[50];
        pid_t pid;
        int status;
        
        if(strcmp(args[0],"quit")==0) return 1;     //exited by quit
        
        strcpy(path,"/bin/");
        strcat(path,args[0]);
        
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
            perror("fork failed");
            exit(2);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {
            if(execvp(path, args) < 0) {        
                perror("execvp failed");
                exit(3);
            }
        }
        else {
            while (wait(&status) != pid)       /* wait for completion  */
                   ;
        }
    }
```

Please help?

Comment: at `parse` Need `pch=strtok(NULL,delimeter);` at end of while-loop. (Need update `pch`)

Comment: When you invoke your shell without any command line arguments, your `strcmp()` calls have undefined behavior.  They might very well segfault.  You should use `argc` to determine whether there is a command-line argument to test.

Comment: Similarly if you invoke it with the `-b` option but no file name argument.

Comment: do not access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameters actually exist.  If the expected command line parameters do not exist, output a USAGE message to stderr then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE  );`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) please consistently indent the code: indent after every opening brace '{',  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level. 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: The posted code does not compile.  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements.  Do you expect us to guess what header files your code actually uses?

Comment: when writing prototypes for functions that have no parameters, in the prototype statement include the type `void` between the parens.  Other wise the compiler will generate code for any number of parameters, rather than for no parameters.

Comment: the function `execute()` is declared to return an `int` value, but the actual function body never returns anything..   Calling `exit()` is NOT satisfying the declaration.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers, like 50, 128, 512. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. Strongly suggest using an enum statement or #define statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: when `fgets()` and other system functions return an error indication, then immediately call `perror()` with an appropriate error message.  The function: `perror()` will output to `stderr` both the error message and the text of why the OS thinks the function failed.

Comment: the `parse()` function only copies the pointer to some area in memory.  When the area changes, the values in the extracted 'commands[]` will be invalid.  Strongly suggest making use of `strdup()`  (of course later, all the duplicated string pointers will need to be passed to free) so the pointers will point to the desired data

Comment: the posted code is prepending `/bin` to the name of item to execute.  However, many/most executable functions are in `/user/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`  and several other places, including in the local directory or the executable name may be prefiaced by `./` or even `/applicationDirectory/`

Comment: None of the `exec*` functions return, unless there was an error, so this line: `if(execvp(path,args)<0)` is not correct.  Suggest: `execvp(path,args); perror( "execvp failed" ); exit( 3 );

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to print all your variables `argv`, `str`, `commands` ... To make sure all is going on as expected there ? It could also help you locate in your script where you segfault. It will take you time, sorry I have no quick answer. For starter`printf("%d", __LINE__)` would print the line number you are at, don't forget to add an explicit statement.
Otherwise you could use gdb. There is quite a learning curve, but it could be useful for another project.